# Multicolored graph based on data frame values

Tags: pandas

Im plotting chart based on the data frame as below., I want to show the graph line in different colour based on the column Condition. Im trying the following code but it shows only one colour throughout the graph.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Day=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods = 60, freq='D'), 
        Utilisation = np.random.rand(60) * 100))

df = df.astype(dtype= {"Utilisation":"int64"})
df['Condition'] = np.where(df.Utilisation < 10, 'Winter', 
                           np.where(df.Utilisation < 30, 'Summer', 'Spring'))

condition_map = {'Winter': 'r', 'Summer': 'k', 'Spring': 'b'}
df[['Utilisation','Day']].set_index('Day').plot(figsize=(10,4), rot=90, 
                                                color=df.Condition.map(condition_map))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I assume you want a graph for each condition.
I would use `groupby` to separate the data.

```
# Color setting
season_color = {'Winter': 'r', 'Summer': 'k', 'Spring': 'b'}

# Create figure and axes
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 4))

# Loop over and plot each group of data
for cond, data in df.groupby('Condition'):
    ax.plot(data.Day, data.Utilisation, color = season_color[cond], label = cond)

# Fix datelabels
f.autofmt_xdate()

f.legend()
f.show()
```

If you truly want the date ticks to be rotated 90 degrees, use `autofmt_xdate(rotation = 90)`

---

**Update:**

If you want to plot everything in a single line it's a bit trickier since a line only can have ***one*** color associated to it.

You could plot a line between each point and split a line if it crosses a "color boundary", or check out this pyplot example: [multicolored line](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html)

Another possibility is to plot a lot of scatter points between each point and create a own `colormap` that represents your color boundaries.

To create a colormap (and norm) I use [`from_levels_and_colors`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.from_levels_and_colors.html)

```
import matplotlib.colors

colors = ['#00BEC5', '#a0c483', '#F9746A']
boundaries = [0, 10, 30, 100]
cm, nrm = matplotlib.colors.from_levels_and_colors(boundaries, colors)
```

To connect each point with next you could `shift` the dataframe, but here I just `zip` the original df with a sliced version

```
from itertools import islice

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,4))
for (i,d0), (i,d1) in zip(df.iterrows(), islice(df.iterrows(), 1, None)):    
    d_range = pd.date_range(d0.Day, d1.Day, freq = 'h')
    y_val = np.linspace(d0.Utilisation, d1.Utilisation, d_range.size)
    ax.scatter(d_range, y_val, c = y_val, cmap = cm, norm = nrm)

f.autofmt_xdate()
f.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I need to draw it in one Chart `colors = {'Summer':'#a0c483', 'Winter':'#00BEC5', 'Spring':'#F9746A'}
plot(figsize=(10,4),rot=90,color= df['Condition'].map(colors))` But the problem us `df['Condition']` always takes first row not corresponding row.

Comment: You mean you want to draw it as a single line that changes color (in segments) based on 'Condition'?